# How can I get a buffer overflow in a global variable?

Tags: c, global-variables, buffer, buffer-overflow

I'm working on detecting and preventing BOF attacks and I'd like to know, how can I overflow a global struct?

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct{
        char name[20];
        char description[10];
} test;


int main(int argc, char **argv){
        if(argc != 2)
                exit(-1);
        *(*(argv+1)+20) = '\x00'; //terminate string after 20 characters

        strcpy(test.name, argv[1]); //no BOF here... stopped at 20
        printf("%s\n", test.name);

        char *desc;
        desc = malloc(10);
        if(!desc){
                printf("Error allocating memory\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        scanf("%s", desc); //no bounds checking - this is where I BOF
        strcpy(test.description, desc); //copy over 10 characters into 10 char buffer
        printf("%s\n", test.description); //this prints out whatever I type in
        //even thousands of characters, despite it having a buffer of 10 chars
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `scanf()` in production if you really want to prevent buffer overflows. `fegts()` to the rescue!

Comment: This is more of a vulnerable file for my testing.

Comment: You overflow a global buffer the same way you do any other buffer type; you store more data in it than there are bytes allocated for it. Perhaps the question is "and what damage does that do", and the answer is the usual: it depends.  Basically, when you overflow a specific global buffer, you write over some other global variables, and what happens next depends on whether the other variable is referenced again, and what it is supposed to hold.  It won't, typically, have function return addresses and the like, so it can be more difficult to exploit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you should copy/paste that as the answer. Very brief yet direct. Perfect.

Comment: The assumption that the memory pointed to by `argv[1]` is writable 20-chars out is itself a stretch.

Comment: `*(*(argv+1)+20) = '\x00'; //terminate string after 20 characters` - if you comment this out, then you will be able to easily overflow a global variable.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll add a strlen(). Thanks for the input!

Comment: @WhozCraig: in theory, I agree with your point. Certainly, the standard says nothing about what might be there. In practice, if `argv[1]` itself is shorter than the 20 bytes, there will either be what was in `argv[2]` (if there was an `argv[2]`), or you'll be pointing at the start of the environment (what would be pointed at by the pointers in `envp` if you wrote `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`.  That's an empirical observation; there is nothing in any standard that guarantees that layout, but it is how most Unix-like systems lay out the memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I concur. I was shocked after so many years in this business a year or so ago to find they're even writable. I was wowed by that in itself, never having the need to really try. If it is pecked out like you say, it certainly *could* work I suppose, bad idea not withstanding. (and +1 on your answer, btw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You overflow a global buffer the same way you do any other buffer type; you store more data in it than there are bytes allocated for it. Perhaps the question is "and what damage does that do?", and the answer is the usual: *it depends*.

Basically, when you overflow a specific global buffer, you write over some other global variables, and what happens next depends on whether the other variable is referenced again, and what it is supposed to hold. It won't, typically, have function return addresses and the like, so it can be more difficult to exploit.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *desc = malloc(10);
> scanf("%s", desc); //no bounds checking - this is where I BOF
> strcpy(test.description, desc); //copy over 10 characters into 10 char buffer
> ```

One of the things you will need to address during testing on modern Linux systems are the calls to `scanf` and `strcpy`. Modern systems use `FORTIFY_SOURCE`, and it tries to remediate some classes of buffer overflows.

FORTIFY_SOURCE uses "safer" variants of high risk functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`. The compiler uses the safer variants when it can deduce the destination buffer size. If the copy would exceed the destination buffer size, then the program calls `abort()`.

To disable FORTIFY_SOURCE for your testing, you should compile the program with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.